# How does dropbox sync files if I set one computer a few days into the future?

Tags: sync, rsync, dropbox

I do not understand how you could sync things correctly if time can be relative between computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't back this up with hard facts, but I would think that the Dropbox client software synchronises/keeps track of its own time (with the Dropbox servers) before syncing.

Answer (score 2):

I do know that when Dropbox sees a discrepancy in date/time stamps it creates the filename + computer name it came from.